# Python C API: Using PyEval_EvalCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Python interpreter from C, and I'm having trouble with `PyEval_EvalCode`.  Basically, I'm writing a C function which takes in an arbitrary string of Python code, compiles it, executes it, and then prints out the result.

The problem is that when I print out the result, I always get `None`, even if the expression obviously doesn't evaluate to `None`.

Here is the code (with error checking and reference counting removed for clarity):

```
void eval(const char* s)
{
    PyCodeObject* code = (PyCodeObject*) Py_CompileString(s, "test", Py_file_input);
    PyObject* main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    PyObject* global_dict = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);
    PyObject* local_dict = PyDict_New();
    PyObject* obj = PyEval_EvalCode(code, global_dict, local_dict);

    PyObject* result = PyObject_Str(obj);
    PyObject_Print(result, stdout, 0);
}
```

I tried calling this function with `"5 + 5"` as the input, and it displayed `None`.  Am I using `PyEval_EvalCode` incorrectly?

Comment: Do we need to insert some Py_INCREF() / Py_DECREF() statements in the code above to avoid memory leaks ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to evaluate an expression, you need to use `Py_eval_input` as an argument to `Py_CompileString`.

My understanding of the matter is that:

- `Py_eval_input` is equivalent to the built-in `eval` -- it evaluates an expression.
- `Py_file_input` is equivalent to `exec` -- It executes Python code, but does not return anything.
- `Py_single_input` evaluates an expression and prints its value -- used in the interpreter.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html#Py_eval_input) for more, but the documentation on this subject is weak.